# designer workflow not starting

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I'm creating a SharePoint List item from a sharepoint designer workflow (create item). The list has a workflow that should be triggered on item creation, however it is not being triggered. If I create the item manually the workflow then IS triggered. I tried creating the item both in SP 2010 with or without impersonation and SP 2013 workflows, but all do not trigger the workflow to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to [this existing question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179787/workflow-not-trigger-when-item-is-created-by-sharepoint-app/180057#180057) would be a good starting point for you in troubleshooting.  I've not experienced this myself, but the answer seems to match up.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me for two reasons:
1. I need a second workflow to be called after the create item, as this workflow has a pause in it and i do not want the parent workflow to pause as well.
2. I can't start a workflow from a 2010 workflow (??)

Comment: any other tips please?

Comment: this actually helped to get me to the right solution. I created a 2010 workflow instead of 2013, set it to start on new item and on changed item and it works.. not sure if it's because it's 2010 not 2013 but it's working now

Comment: There are differences between the 2010 and 2013 workflows.  A more experienced guy at my work never uses the 2013 ones, though that's not to say they can't be useful.  Our SP deployment only uses 2010 workflows though.  You mention initiating workflows, I would just mention generally that it is also possible to initiate a workflow from a 'Timer Job' on the server, I mention this in case you might need to explore that option for a future workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Can´t add comments because of my reputation, so an answer it is.

Which SP Version are you using? SP10, 13, 16, online?
Tried it on SP Online and everything worked like a charm. Example: ParentWorkflow on "ParentList" starts on CreatItem and creates with "Create Item" activity a list item in "ChildList" wich will start "ChildWorkflow" automatically on list item creation.

If you use on premises instead of sharepoint online check following answer: [SPD 2013 Workflow not starting automatically on Item Creation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221751/spd-2013-workflow-not-starting-automatically-on-item-creation)

If nothing helps try following: Create the whiched item via create item activity and after that use the update item activity to commit a change to the previously created item. Your second worklow should also have the start option on change.

I dont think the following will help you, but maybe others:

1. Please check if your are currently logged in as System Account. If so, use a "normal" useraccount with administrative permissions like site collection admin or owner.
2. Also publish your workflow as this account and never as System Account.
3. Check the workflow start options, reselect it, save and publish it again on both workflows. Also note number one, never as system account.
4. If on premises: check your ulslog. Is there probably a system error which will stop the create item activity?